# SNOW PIPE status - LastRecievedMessageTimestamp > LastForwardedMessageTImestamp. are messages not forwarded?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

[image]

### SNOW PIPE status:

- I  usually validate by looking at LastForwardedMessageTImestamp > LastRecievedMessageTimestamp as **"Receiving and Forwarding of Data"**  is complete.
- In this pipe status LastRecievedMessageTimestamp is greater than LastForwardedMessageTImestamp. **Does it mean SQS is not forwarding messages to SNOWPIPE?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may read the following to get more information about Pipe Status:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/system_pipe_status.html

lastReceivedMessageTimestamp:

Timestamp of the last message received from the queue. **Note that this message might not apply to the specific pipe, e.g., if the path/prefix associated with the message does not match the path/prefix in the pipe definition. In addition, only messages triggered by created data objects are consumed by auto-ingest pipes.**

lastForwardedMessageTimestamp:

Timestamp of the last “create object” event message with a matching path/prefix that was forwarded to the pipe.

I think it explains why lastReceivedMessageTimestamp could be greater than lastForwardedMessageTimestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Usually your **notification_channel** is the same for all the **PIPES** in your account.
All pipes are linked to the same **SQS Queue** so they all receive message when a file notification is triggered. That's the reason why all your pipes should have the same **lastReceivedMessageTimestamp** at a given time.

The pipes will forward the message to your given **COPY** instruction only if it matches with the location/pattern configured in your pipe definition.